# Do I need a current limiting resistor with an industrial rail DIN optocoupler?

Tags: resistors, circuit-design, opto-isolator, current-limiting, industrial

I'm going to use this industrial opto-coupler:
[Optocoupleur RS PRO, montage Rail DIN, 6 mA](https://fr.rs-online.com/web/p/modules-a-relais-statiques/9054277)
In its specs document they don't mention the need of a current limiting resistor. I always  add a current limiting resistor when using an opto-coupler chip in my PCBs, but not sure if I need it with this kind of industrial opto-coupler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does these pictures in the [RS data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/1345/0900766b81585e5b.pdf) help you understand: -

[image]
[image]

The 6 mA will probably be when the voltage input is at a maximum or, there may be internal circuits that keep it fairly constant over the input range.

Comment: I saw it, for me its not obvious... They don't specify an input current, just voltage... but they also include a rated input current... I don't know if I'm supposed to limit the current using an external resistor to around 6mA or if this device already includes some kind of current limiting circuit.

Comment: @PedroNF But surely if you know that a device takes in 5V to 30V, why would it not work if directly applied with a voltage of 5 to 30 volts, regardless of current?

Comment: @PedroNF if you look at the French version of the data sheet, they talk about the 6 mA being a nominal value rather than a rated value. The value being described as "nominal" makes more sense and aligns with my explanation. Does calling it 6 mA nominal help you? Also, if you look at the dimensional diagram and focus on the internal circuit layout, you'll see that there is much more circuitry on the input side than what a basic opto-isolator has (just a diode basically). In other words, the "effort" of calculating a series resistor is not needed at all.

Comment: [Diagram of internal circuitry showing a fairly complex input conditioning circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Nny.png). French description of input current: *Courant d'entrée nominal 6 mA*

Comment: Nice, you x-rayed the thing :-) Ok, I agree with you that it already contains a smart input circuit, no need for the extra effort of calculating a resistor